# Django - How to show messages under ajax function

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I am using AjaxForm plugin to submit my form without refresh. like:

```
$('#my_form_id').ajaxForm(function(){

        //something on success or fail
    });
```

this works correctly. when i click submit button it saves form datas without refresh. But before this ; i had django messages on my template file like:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div id="notice" align="center">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

what this code does is displaying notifications if post saved correctly or something failed.

now; i can't do that. i dont understand how i can use these messages tags with ajax functions.

it just saves the post. no notifications.

thank you.

edit :

add_post url : `url(r'^admin/post/add/$', view='add_post',name='add_post'),`

related view :

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add_post(request):
    template_name = 'add.html'
    owner = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            titleform = form.cleaned_data['title']
            bodyform = form.cleaned_data['body']
            checkform = form.cleaned_data['isdraft']

            n = Post(title=titleform, body=bodyform, isdraft=checkform, owner=owner)
            n.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                'New post created successfully!')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING,
                'Please fill in all fields!')
    else:
        form = addForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'form': form, 'owner': owner,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You should paste your url and view.

Comment: added url and view part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are the tools/methods that helped me to solve the problem.  First, I have a helper utility method called `render_to_json`:

```
# `data` is a python dictionary
def render_to_json(request, data):
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False),
        mimetype=request.is_ajax() and "application/json" or "text/html"
    )
```

I have a `messages.html` template to render the necessary html for the popup message(s):

```
{% for message in messages %}
<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

When create a message in response to an AJAX request, I use Django's `render_to_string` to package the message(s) into a string that gets stored in a `data` dictionary, which then uses my `render_to_json` to return an appropriate response:

```
def my_custom_view(request)
    # ...  your view code
    data = {
        'msg': render_to_string('messages.html', {}, RequestContext(request)),
    }
    return render_to_json(request, data)
```

Then, in my jQuery `$.post(...)` callback function, I check to see if the `response` object has a `msg` attribute, and then insert the contents of `response.msg` into the DOM where I want it needs to be, with jQuery transitions if desired.  My `base.html` template contains the `<ul>` container for the messages:

```
<ul id="popup-messages-content">
    {% include 'messages.html' %}
</ul>
```

Note that the above includes the `messages.html` for the case when you want to display messages on an actual page load (non-AJAX request) - it is blank if there are no messages, but the `<ul>` is still available to push AJAX-received messages into.

The last piece is the Javascript function (requires jQuery) I use in any `$.post(...)` callbacks to show the messages:

```
function showPopupMessage(content) {
    var elMessages = $('#popup-messages-content');
    if (elMessages.length && content) {
        elMessages.html(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this provided the answer you needed, can you mark it as such?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing... Sorry for the late response. just accepted it :)

Answer (score 11):

You just create your messages as always and before sending the response you put them into a list of dicts:

```
django_messages = []

for message in messages.get_messages(request):
    django_messages.append({
        "level": message.level,
        "message": message.message,
        "extra_tags": message.tags,
})
```

Then you add any data and your messages and serialize it, e.g.:

```
data = {}
data['success'] = success
data['messages'] = django_messages

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Finally at your ajax:

```
success: function(data){
    success = data.success;
    update_messages(data.messages);
    if (success){
        ...                                                                             
    }
},
```

And the update_messages function:

```
function update_messages(messages){
    $("#div_messages").html("");
    $.each(messages, function (i, m) {
        $("#div_messages").append("<div class='alert alert-"+m.level+"''>"+m.message+"</div>");
    }); 
}
```

It works perfectly and I found it very easily to implement.

**Edit**: There was a suggestion to change the last piece of code in order to use a mapping for the levels. This does not apply to version this answer was written for, since level was actually a string. In version 4.0 it is now a number, see docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#creating-custom-message-levels). This would be the new snippet. Thanks for the suggestion @codingfactory1:

```
function update_messages(messages){
    const levels = {20: 'info', 25: 'success', 30: 'warning', 40: 'error'}
    $("#div_messages").html("");
    $.each(messages, function (i, m) {
        $("#div_messages").append("<div class='alert alert-"+levels[m.level]+"''>"+m.message+"</div>");
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Should your `m.div_messages` variables not be `m.level` and `m.message` respectively?

Comment: Also do you not want `message.level_tag` rather than `message.level`?

Comment: You are right about the variables, it was just a mistake when translating the code to english. About level_tag vs level I'm not sure, I don't actually use it on my code. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @steven2308 dude, you're first link above is broken!  :P please fix

Comment: @AbstractSpacecraft I could not find it, it was ~ 6 years ago, sorry. Anyway. for the given question this answer is complete, no need for external sources.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple idea.

Add a placeholder for your messages in layout.html, this allows appending new messages in javascript:

```
<div id="messages">
{% for message in messages %}
    <div id="notice" align="center">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div id="notice" align="center">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In add.html, add **another one** like:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="hidden-messages" style="display:none">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div id="notice" align="center">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

And ajaxForm would look like:

```
$('#your_form_id').ajaxForm({
    success: function(responseText) {
        var newMessages = $(responseText).find('.hidden-messages').html();
        $('#messages').append(newMessages);
    },
});
```

Comment: hmmm. can you write me some explain code? to me understand it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

in template

```
<div id="ajax_message">
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}  fade show">
                {{ message|safe }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

after ajax_send start function

```
$("#ajax_message").load("this_url #ajax_message");
```

or

```
function alert_message() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $("#ajax_message").load(pathname+" #ajax_message");
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting this to work, but I upvoted to summon you :P

Answer (score 0):

## How to do this when using django-bootstrap5 lib:

#### Make an AJAX get request to a messages view that simply returns a custom messages.html template.

Okay, I reviewed some of the work done so far on this problem, and I came up with a neat solution that is probably a duplicate of the above, however, my post is distinct from those in that I am specifically solving this problem for coders using **django-bootstrap5**. So if that is you, then read further and this may solve your problem.

Here `<DefaultApp>` is the default app that some IDE's create for a Django project.  My current project is called `AbstractSpacecraft` and it has a subfolder called `AbstractSpacecraft` also, which contains `settings.py` and which I refer to as the default app.

`<DjangoProject>/<DefaultApp>/javascript_tools.js`:

```
window.messages_tag_id = "#django-messages-div";
window.messages_url = null;

function load_html_from_url(url, elem) {
    $.get(url, function(data, status) {
        elem.html(data);
    });   
}

function display_django_messages() {
    messagesDiv = $(window.messages_tag_id);
    messagesDiv.empty();
    load_html_from_url(window.messages_url, messagesDiv);
}

function post_string_to_url(data, url)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {         // Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
            if ('msg' in data) {
                const msg = data['msg'];
                console.log(msg);
                display_django_messages();
            }
        },
        error : function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            // Provide a bit more info about the error to the console:
            if (errmsg) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' + errmsg);
                display_django_messages();
            }
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);             
        }
    });
}

function csrf_safe_method(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function setup_ajax_csrf_token(csrf_token) { 
    // BUGFIX.  This took hours to get to work!  
    // And remember the csrf_token line at the top of template
    window.csrf_token = csrf_token;
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrf_safe_method(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`

`<DjangoProject>/templates/<AppName>/your_template.html` (only relevant parts):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        // Remember to call this!
        setup_ajax_csrf_token("{{ csrf_token }}");   

        let ui = window.ui;
            
        $("#diagram-name-form").submit((event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const data = {
                "diagram name" : $("#diagram-name-input").val(),
                "diagram id" : "{{ diagram_id }}",
            };
            const set_name_url = "{% url 'set_model_string' Model='Diagram' field='name'%}";
            
            post_string_to_url(data, set_name_url, "{% url 'messages' %}");
        });
    });        
    
</script>

 .....

<div class="form-outline">
    <form class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center" method="post"
        id="diagram-name-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
    
        <input type="text" id="diagram-name-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Diagram name?" />
    </form>
</div>
```

`<DjangoProject>/templates/<DefaultApp>/messages.html`:

```
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

{% autoescape off %}{% bootstrap_messages %}{% endautoescape %}
```

`<DjangoProject/<DefaultApp>/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, View

class MessagesView(View):
    template_name = 'AbstractSpacecraft/messages.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

`<DjangoProject>/<DefaultApp>/base.html`:

```
{% block bootstrap5_content %}
  {% block as_navbar %}  <!-- as = AbstractSpacecraft -->
   ....
  {% endblock %}
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="row" id="django-messages-div">
                {% autoescape off %}{% bootstrap_messages %}{% endautoescape %}              
              </div>              
              {% block content %}{% endblock %}                
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
....
```

Basically, after we receive the OK from the ajax POST request, we do an ajax GET request, it might work now that everything is working, but I was not able to get `messagesDiv.load(url)` to work, via viewing the Network tab in Chrome DevTools and under the traffic analyzer you should see a POST request followed by a GET request when everything is working.

The ajax GET simply gets an `messages.html` template that we then fill with the freshly known about messages.    We make sure to clear the `messageDiv` first though so the messages can't stack up on the gui.

Comment: Okay, `elem.load(url)` seems to work now (and was probably always working).  So please use *it* instead of an AJAX get.