# send django message from a template file

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to set message using [django message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/) from inside a template file?

```
{% if not userIsLoggedIn %}
   <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a> 
   {# I want to send message to the user who click this buy button on the login page #}
{% elif not game_bought and game.price != 0   %}
   <form action="/buy" method="POST">
       <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buy">
   </form>
{% endif %}
```

I can think of a hackish way of doing it by using query string, but it would be nice if I could use django's message framework.

Comment: Possibly this answer can solve your problem, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13257437/5518973

Answer (score 1):

There are two wrong assumptions here.

Firstly, you can't do anything "from the template". Everything that requires user interaction must be done via some kind of request that is processed in a view. If you want that to be transparent to the user, you could use some an Ajax request, but it does still need to be a request.

Secondly, Django's messaging framework is not suitable for sending messages between users. The messages are stored in the user's session, and there is no way for one user to modify another user's session. There are plenty of third-party messaging libraries for Django, or you could roll your own fairly simply.

Comment: This is not for sending messages between users. It was just to redirect user to login page with an error message saying that they need to login first before buying. But anyway, I got your first point, I should do it in the target view instead on the template. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the Django messaging framework to add the message in the view, then display it to the user in the template. See the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Sorry but I am asking about the possibility of adding message from the template file instead of from the view

Comment: Why would you need to do that in the template?

Comment: as I wrote in the question, I want non logged in user who click that buy button, gets redirected to login page with an error message saying that they need to login first before buying. Anyway, on second thought, it got me thinking that I should probably do that in the buy view instead of putting if else on the view